# Multi-dimensional vector borrowing

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a coding exercise, but I've ran into a wall regarding multi-dimensional vectors and borrowing.

The code is accessible in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=82293661cb8ac049b25a323262b5738e), but I'll add here a snippet for reference:

```rust
type Matrix = Rc<RefCell<Vec<Vec<String>>>>;

/// sequence -> target string
/// dictionary -> array of 'words' that can be used to construct the 'sequence'
/// returns -> 2d array of all the possible combinations to create the 'sequence' from the 'dictionary'
pub fn all_construct<'a>(sequence: &'a str, dictionary: &'a [&str]) -> Matrix {
    let memo: Rc<RefCell<HashMap<&str, Matrix>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(HashMap::new()));
    all_construct_memo(sequence, dictionary, Rc::clone(&memo))
}

fn all_construct_memo<'a>(
    sequence: &'a str,
    dictionary: &'a [&str],
    memo: Rc<RefCell<HashMap<&'a str, Matrix>>>,
) -> Matrix {
    if memo.borrow().contains_key(sequence) {
        return Rc::clone(&memo.borrow()[sequence]);
    }

    if sequence.is_empty() {
        return Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));
    }

    let ways = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));
    for word in dictionary {
        if let Some(new_sequence) = sequence.strip_prefix(word) {
            let inner_ways = all_construct_memo(new_sequence, dictionary, Rc::clone(&memo));

            for mut entry in inner_ways.borrow_mut().into_iter() { // error here
                entry.push(word.to_string());
                ways.borrow_mut().push(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    memo.borrow_mut().insert(sequence, Rc::clone(&ways));
    Rc::clone(&ways)
}
```

The code doesn't compile.

Questions:

1. This feel overly complicated. Is there a simpler way to do it?

   1.1 For the `Matrix` type, I tried getting by with just `Vec<Vec<String>>`, but that didn't get me very far. **What's the way to properly encode a 2d Vector that allows for mutability and sharing, without using extra crates?**

   1.2. Is there a better way to pass the memo object?
2. Not really understanding the compiler error here. Can you help me with that?

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `RefMut<'_, Vec<Vec<String>>>`
  --> src/lib.rs:31:30
   |
31 |             for mut entry in inner_ways.borrow_mut().into_iter() { // error here
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Vec<Vec<String>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `for entry in inner_ways.borrow_mut().iter_mut() { ... ways.borrow_mut().push(entry.clone()); }`

Comment: `memo` does not need to be an `Rc<RefCell<_>>`, a simple `memo: &mut HashMap<&'a str, Matrix>` should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2d vecs work fine, and for jagged arrays like yours, your implementation is correct. Your issues stem from a needless use of Rc and RefCell. Because of the way you're calling things, a single, mutable reference will work.

Consider the following, modified, example:

```rust
type Vec2<T> = Vec<Vec<T>>;

fn all_constructs<'a>(sequence: &'a str, segments: &[&'a str]) -> Vec2<&'a str> {
    let mut cache = HashMap::new();
    all_constructs_memo(sequence, segments, &mut cache)
}

fn all_constructs_memo<'a>(
    sequence: &'a str,
    segments: &[&'a str],
    cache: &mut HashMap<&'a str, Vec2<&'a str>>
) -> Vec2<&'a str> {
    // If we have the answer cached, return the cache
    if let Some(constructs) = cache.get(sequence) {
        return constructs.to_vec();
    }
    // We don't have it cached, so figure it out
    let mut constructs = Vec::new();
    for segment in segments {
        if *segment == sequence {
            constructs.push(vec![*segment]);
        } else if let Some(sub_sequence) = sequence.strip_suffix(segment) {
            let mut sub_constructs = all_constructs_memo(sub_sequence, segments, cache);
            sub_constructs.iter_mut().for_each(|c| c.push(segment));
            constructs.append(&mut sub_constructs);
        }
    }
    cache.insert(sequence, constructs.clone());
    return constructs;
}
```

It's identical, execpt for 4 differences:

1.) I removed all Rc and RefCell. There is a single Hashmap reference

2.) Instead of having `all_constructs_memo("", ...) -> Vec::new()`, I just added a branch in the iterator `if *segment == sequence` to test for single-segment matches that way.

3.) I wrote `Vec2` instead of `Matrix`

4.) `strip_suffix` instead of `strip_prefix`, just because adding to the end of vecs is a little more efficient than adding to the front.

Here's a playground link with tests against a non-memoized reference implementation
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b488aafda6466629c17c8a7de8f3e42